# html slim link_to undefined method error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

In my rails project, I ran `rake routes` and got the following output:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                              Controller#Action
obelisk_callflow_nodes GET    /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes(.:format)          obelisk/nodes#index
                       POST   /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes(.:format)          obelisk/nodes#create
new_obelisk_callflow_node GET    /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes/new(.:format)      obelisk/nodes#new
edit_obelisk_callflow_node GET    /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes/:id/edit(.:format) obelisk/nodes#edit
 obelisk_callflow_node GET    /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes/:id(.:format)      obelisk/nodes#show
                       PATCH  /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes/:id(.:format)      obelisk/nodes#update
                       PUT    /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes/:id(.:format)      obelisk/nodes#update
                       DELETE /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes/:id(.:format)      obelisk/nodes#destroy
     obelisk_callflows GET    /obelisk/callflows(.:format)                             obelisk/callflows#index
                       POST   /obelisk/callflows(.:format)                             obelisk/callflows#create
  new_obelisk_callflow GET    /obelisk/callflows/new(.:format)                         obelisk/callflows#new
 edit_obelisk_callflow GET    /obelisk/callflows/:id/edit(.:format)                    obelisk/callflows#edit
      obelisk_callflow GET    /obelisk/callflows/:id(.:format)                         obelisk/callflows#show
                       PATCH  /obelisk/callflows/:id(.:format)                         obelisk/callflows#update
                       PUT    /obelisk/callflows/:id(.:format)                         obelisk/callflows#update
                       DELETE /obelisk/callflows/:id(.:format)                         obelisk/callflows#destroy
```

I have a html.slim file for showing all the callflows (i.e.obelisk/nodes#index). In this file, I want to add a button to show the nodes of each callflow (i.e. connect that button to `obelisk_callflow_nodes GET    /obelisk/callflows/:callflow_id/nodes`)

I've tried `= link_to 'Nodes', obelisk_callflow_nodes_path(callflow_id: c.id), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-primary'` where c is a callflow object. I've checked that c is what I want because I have `c.name` rendering properly. However, I'm getting the following error:

`undefined method`obelisk_callflow_nodes_path' for #<#:0x00007fb3d5abebc8>`

I've checked that I do have an index method for my Obelisk::NodesController

Comment: try doing it like this
`obelisk_callflow_nodes_path(c.id)`, you don't need to set the name of the param, just pass them in the order they are configured in the route

Comment: stop rails server, then `spring stop` and start the server again. Try this.

Comment: Tried `obelisk_callflow_nodes_path(c.id)`  and got error undefined method `obelisk_callflow_nodes_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007efc40ea1fa8>:0x00007efc4092ceb0>

Comment: and are you sure c.id have a valid id? can you put a screeenshot of the error?

Comment: Can you show the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the routes so that I no longer user `namespace obelisk` so the routes don't start with /obelisk/. This fixes the problem. I know it might not be the best solution but in this case it has worked for the purpose of my project.